# Qt Designer causes no changes in the application

Tags: c++, qt

I've been trying to make a simple test application in Qt Designer using Qt Quick Application.  However, nothing I implement in the Qt Designer gets shown when I run it. For example, the "Testing Qt Designer" text doesn't show up, since I implemented it in the designer.  I have tried to clean the build, and building it again.  I also deleted the whole build folder and tried to build it again, however that doesn't work.  Can anyone help me get Qt Designer to work?

I am using Qt Creator 5.3 on Windows 8.1 64 bit.

main.qml:

```
import QtQuick 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 1.1

ApplicationWindow {
visible: true
width: 640
height: 480
title: qsTr("Hello World")

menuBar: MenuBar {
    Menu {
        title: qsTr("File")
        MenuItem {
            text: qsTr("Exit")
            onTriggered: Qt.quit();
        }
    }
}

Text {
    text: qsTr("Hello World")
    anchors.centerIn: parent
}

Text {
    id: text1
    x: -258
    y: -151
    width: 264
    height: 76
    text: qsTr("Testing Qt Designer")
    font.pixelSize: 25
}
}
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
QApplication app(argc, argv);

QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:///main.qml")));

return app.exec();
}
```

testApp5.pro:

```
TEMPLATE = app

QT += qml quick widgets

SOURCES += main.cpp

RESOURCES += qml.qrc

# Additional import path used to resolve QML modules in Qt Creator's code model
QML_IMPORT_PATH =

# Default rules for deployment.
include(deployment.pri)
```

deployment.pri:

```
android-no-sdk {
target.path = /data/user/qt
export(target.path)
INSTALLS += target
} else:android {
x86 {
    target.path = /libs/x86
} else: armeabi-v7a {
    target.path = /libs/armeabi-v7a
} else {
    target.path = /libs/armeabi
}
export(target.path)
INSTALLS += target
} else:unix {
isEmpty(target.path) {
    qnx {
        target.path = /tmp/$${TARGET}/bin
    } else {
        target.path = /opt/$${TARGET}/bin
    }
    export(target.path)
}
INSTALLS += target
}

export(INSTALLS)
```

Answer (score 0):

I sometimes run into a weird problem lately where it looks like the qrc-based deployment fails; files that were changed do not cause rcc to be run and hence your application doesn't reflect changes you make. It seems *similar* to [QTBUG-13334](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-13334).

You can verify if you are running into this issue by making a change to your QML file, either through the editor or the designer, and then checking the `Compile Output` window. If you see something like

```
mingw32-make[1]: Nothing to be done for 'first'.
```

even after making a change before deploying, then you may be running into this issue as well.

### Workaround

Try going to `Projects > Run` and under `Deployment`, click `Add Deploy Step` and then choose `Make`. In the `Make arguments` field, type "clean". Then add another `Make` deploy step, this time with no arguments. This will force your project to be rebuilt each time you run the application - not a huge deal for small projects.

Note that the [plain green arrow](http://qt-project.org/doc/qtcreator-3.1/creator-quick-tour.html#application-output) in the `Application Output` window will run your application's executable directly, bypassing any deployment steps, should you wish to re-run the application several times.

Comment: It doesn't look like I have that output in my "Compile Output" window.   I tried the workaround anyway, however that didn't work either.